# Android layout with black background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I'm building a very simple app, where I find 2 main problem:

1- All of a sudden, my layout activity background got black when debugging on the Galaxy Note (GT-N7000) while it is white (correct color) when I run the app on Android Studio's emulator.

Here is part of my layout file, where I include another layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/act_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="it.asis.magazzino2.Search">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bBack"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_revert"
            android:onClick="showMenu"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/word_to_search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="54dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text=""
            android:hint="@string/stringa_cerca"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bShowScanner"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:onClick="showScanner"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bDoSearch"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:onClick="searchWord"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <include layout="@layout/materiale_magazzino"/>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.asis.magazzino2" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Add"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Search"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here my styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="textViewMaterialeLabel" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">#5d5d5d</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center</item>
</style>
<style name="textViewMaterialeValore" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">#5d5d5d</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">13dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center</item>
</style>
```

Here my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.asis.magazzino2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
}
```

What I tried:

-setting background from class

-setting background on general layout, scrollview, included layout

-changing theme (from default *android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar* to *android:Theme.Holo.Light*)

What is going on with that background??

2- My app has an EditText field with a button that (when clicked) uses BarcodeScanner API to read barcodes (see first code here above). When the barcode has been correctly read, IF I tap on the EditTExt field, the keyboard compare and I'm not able to hide it anymore... Even more, the "Done" button disappear.
The only solution I found is hiding it from class, like this:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.act_search);
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mainLayout.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: what is the version of both the devices?

Comment: 2. You can press back button to hide the keyboard

Comment: 1. Can you show @layout/materiale_magazzino?

Answer (score 0):

Go to values/styles.xml and create a style

```
 <style name="SplashTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```

Change @drawable/splash to #FFFFFF (or better @color/white and include white to colors.xml) Then go to Manifest and put that style to activity

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"/>
```

That's all. It loads faster than the view of the activity, so you can have whatever color or image you want.